# Can I set application executable type in .hta not .exe in UWP

Tags: uwp, hta

I bring the hta application (HTML Applications) to UWP (Universal Windows Platform ), but Application Executable must be only .exe file. 
Expression mshta.exe .hta does not work, since is required regexp pattern ".+.(exe)". 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but Application Executable must be only .exe file.

If you want to use [Desktop App Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) tool to bring your app to UWP, you're not able to do it since the tool only support Win32 apps and apps that you've created by using .NET 4.6.1.

For existing web applications, Windows 10 makes it easy for you to create a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app that packages your website for publishing to the Store.You could make your app a hosted web app with just a website URL following [Convert your web application to a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/hwa-create-windows).